# How to edit WordPress posts/pages HTML using text editor or IDE?

Tags: html, wordpress, eclipse, phpstorm

I frequently need to edit the HTML of a WordPress site. But the HTML text box of WordPress editor is very basic and not easy to work with. I would copy the whole text to Sublime Text or any html editor, edit, then copy back to the WordPress box.

How do the professionals do it? Is there any editor or IDE that support this process? (I also use PhpStorm and Eclipse, but with them I also do the copy, edit, copy).

Comment: You can try with the https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ -- classic editor of wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Typically, we are not doing changes on live servers for any WordPress sites directly. We will have a copy of the WordPress site on our local machines, where we can open the page directly. Once we have everything working the way we expect, we will ensure we have a valid backup, and then upload the changed files via any of several different methods.

Sometimes if there is just a small fix, I will use the editor for the theme or plugin, but for most development I keep a local version. For this, the All-In-One Migration Tool is fantastic.

As for using an IDE to directly change the files - that would be more of a networking/server question to get direct access to the files. It wouldn't be something that can be set up through WordPress and would be more complex then setting up a local.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I do have a local server set up. But it is not relevant in this question. The question is: is there a way to set up a local IDE/text editor to edit the HTML of the pages/posts, instead of using the Wordpress editor, which is quite basic?

As for opening the files, well, sometimes there are no files to open, as posts/pages are saved as such in the Wordpress database.